# C# gdal read mssql spatial to geojson

Tags: c#, sql-server, geojson, gdal, spatial-data

```
        Gdal.AllRegister();
         //为了支持中文路径，请添加下面这句代码
        OSGeo.GDAL.Gdal.SetConfigOption("GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8", "NO");
         //为了使属性表字段支持中文，请添加下面这句
        OSGeo.GDAL.Gdal.SetConfigOption("SHAPE_ENCODING", "");
        Ogr.RegisterAll();
        OSGeo.OGR.Driver outDriver = Ogr.GetDriverByName("GeoJSON");
        OSGeo.OGR.DataSource outDataSource =    outDriver.CreateDataSource("aaa.geojson",null);
        DataSource pnn3 = Ogr.Open("MSSQL:server=192.168.1.9,1433;database=KS_DataBase;UId=sa;PWD=sa", 0);

         OSGeo.OGR.Layer layer = pnn3.ExecuteSQL("select * from KS_HXStation", null, "");
        OSGeo.OGR.Feature f;
        layer.ResetReading();
```

I don't know how to take the mssql spatial data transfer Geojson is.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
string sqlConn = "MSSQL:server=[IP];database=[DB];uid=[id]; pwd=[pwd];tables=[tablName];";
string filePath = $@"D:\shp\shpFile.shp";

// 註冊所有的驅動 
Ogr.RegisterAll();

// in order to support chinese path
//OSGeo.GDAL.Gdal.SetConfigOption("GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8", "NO");

// in order to support chinese attribute (CP950 for big5, CP936 for GB)
// reference: http://blog.xuite.net/ebeaoi/beast/9836928-%E7%B7%A8%E7%A2%BC%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C--charset%E5%8F%8Acodepage
Gdal.SetConfigOption("SHAPE_ENCODING", "CP950 | CP936");

// auto dispose DataSource
using (DataSource ds = Ogr.Open(sqlConn, 0))
{
    // load first layer
    Layer oLayer = ds.GetLayerByIndex(0);

    // output file type
    var outDriver = Ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile");

    // auto dispose DataSource
    using (var targetDataSet = outDriver.CreateDataSource(filePath, null))
    {
        targetDataSet.CopyLayer(oLayer, oLayer.GetName(), null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var driver = Ogr.GetDriverByName("GeoJSON");
var trgPath = "";  //export geojson destination path
var trgDataset = driver.CreateDataSource(trgPath, null);
trgDataset.CopyLayer(layer, layer.GetName(), null);
trgDataset.Dispose();
```